# Bootstrap dropdown clicked color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using navbar from getbootstrap.com css page and i'm now editing it to fit my needs. I've done most stuff but can't figure out how to change this color here (white-ish one):
http://image.prntscr.com/image/75cbf6b49f3b48eab11f28a6aeca8ae8.png
Is this :active state at all ? 
what I've tried:

```
.navbar .dropdown-toggle:active{
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

and same for .dropdown. This is the code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right m-r-0">
                @if(Auth::check())
                <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="{{Auth::user()->avatar}}" alt="" class="profileimg">  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
                <li></li>
                @else
             <li><a href="{{route('steamauth')}}"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_01.png" alt=""></a></li>
             @endif
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.navbar-default` Bootstrap is targeting the following for `background-color` of the open navbar dropdown:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Try targeting the following for your `.navbar` dropdown as you are not using `.navbar-default`

```
.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4uag36k/1/) demonstrating background color setting for open dropdown (after it has been clicked).

Comment: This change color of toggle but when it's compacted  (for small devices) like this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/2b8ac416322746308e9dec82fef08e8c.png

Comment: Normal version is still same

Comment: It did change bg color but not when clicked .i tired focus,active but still get that whiteish

Comment: I've updated my answer with different selectors as well as a jsfiddle demonstrating the color changing on click. It should work with `inherit`, but you may need to explicitly set the color. Hopefully that helps!